# New background image for each MDlite card

Tags: html, css, material-design, material-ui

First post here on StackOverflow but longtime user. I am trying to add two MDlite cards to my website, each with a different background image, but the last-declared background image always shows for both. Any help is very much appreciated. Here is the full code you can plop into any browser to see the issue (sorry for formatting, doing this on my phone):

```
                <!doctype html>

            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8">
                <title>Website Title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Percula Creative">
                <meta name="author" content="Percula Creative Author">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.deep_purple-orange.min.css" />
                <script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.1/material.min.js"></script>  
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

            <!--[if IE]><link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico"><![endif]-->
                <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png">
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- Uses a transparent header that draws on top of the layout's background -->
            <style>
            .demo-layout-transparent {
              background: url('../assets/demos/transparent.jpg') center / cover;
            }
            .demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
            .demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
              /* This background is dark, so we set text to white. Use 87% black instead if
                 your background is light. */
              color: white;
            }
            </style>

            <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
            <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
              <header class="mdl-layout__header">
                <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
                  <!-- Title -->
            <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none; color:white" class="mdl-layout-title">Website Title</a>
                  <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
                  <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
                  <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
                  <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="apps.html">Apps</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
                    <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact</a>
                  </nav>
                </div>
              </header>
              <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
                <span class="mdl-layout-title">Website</span>
                <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Apps</a>
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">About</a>
                  <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Contact</a>
                </nav>
              </div>
              <main class="mdl-layout__content" style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
                <div class="page-content" >


                    <div style="width:80%; max-width:780px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 16px">
            <!-- Wide card with share menu button --> <style> .demo-card-wide.mdl-card { width: 100%; } .demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title { color: #fff; height: 176px; background: URL('http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/minions-03.png') center / cover; } .demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu { color: #fff; } </style> 
            <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp""> 
            <div class="mdl-card__title"> 
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h2> </div> 
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor1...</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border"> 
            <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" href="">Download</a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="mdl-card__menu"> 
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"> 
            <i class="material-icons">share</i> 
            </button> 
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>




                    <div style="width:80%; max-width:780px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 16px">
            <!-- Wide card with share menu button --> <style> .demo-card-wide.mdl-card { width: 100%; } .demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title { color: #fff; height: 176px; background: URL('http://i2.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6379795.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Minion.jpg') center / cover; } .demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__menu { color: #fff; } </style> 
            <div class="demo-card-wide mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp""> 
            <div class="mdl-card__title"> 
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text"></h2> </div> 
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
            <p>Lorem Ipsum dolor2...</p>
            </div> 
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border"> 
            <a class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" href="">Download</a> 
            </div> 

            <div class="mdl-card__menu"> 
            <button class="mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect"> 
            <i class="material-icons">share</i> 
            </button> 
            </div>

            </div>
            </div>


                </div>
              </main>
            </div>


            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you've inlined your CSS twice into the page, and the second is overriding the first.  This line of CSS is effecting both divs, not just the first or second.

```
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title { color: #fff; height: 176px; background: URL('http://www.imagenspng.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/minions-03.png') center / cover; }
```

You'll need to create two separate rules, one for each div if you want two different background images in each.

In short do the following:

1) Delete the entire second `<style>...</style>` block

2) Add a new class to the second div so it becomes

```
<div class="mdl-card__title second">
```

3) Add a new css rule to your first `<style>...</style>` block like this

```
.demo-card-wide > .mdl-card__title.second { color: #fff; height: 176px; background: URL('http://i2.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article6379795.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Minion.jpg') center / cover; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked perfectly. Unfortunately I am too new to StackOverflow so I cannot mark this as the correct answer but thank you very much.